# Bug? Or what? Why it returns internal functions?

Tags: version-10

Using version 10.0.1 I input:

```
FullSimplify[(Pi^s Zeta[1 - s] Sin[(Pi s)/2] 2^(s - 1))/Zeta[s]]
```

Mathematica returns:

```
Simplify`SimplifyGamma[
 Simplify`SimplifyGamma[1/2 Gamma[s] Sin[\[Pi] s]]]
```

Comment: Numerically, the result appears to be ok:  if I insert $\,s=0.32$, I get $1.18027$ for both expressions.  In fact, $\Gamma(0.32) = 2.79575$ is not correct.

Comment: @QuantumDot yes, my bad, but still the question about internal functions remains...

Comment: On my 32 bit Linux version 10.0 the result is without internal functions.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on 10.0.1 Linux. I simply got `1/2 Gamma[s] Sin[\[Pi] s]`

Comment: @Yi Wang I also started to get answers like the following: Developer`GammaSimplify[-1]^(-1 + 
  x) (C Developer`GammaSimplify[-1] + x Developer`GammaSimplify[0]) Exitting the kernel does not help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. A clean kernel on 10.0.1 on Win7 64 gives "1/2 Gamma[s] Sin[\[Pi] s]". @Annixx - what OS are you running on?

Comment: @Ymareth Win7 Now it says"Cannot open C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\Kernel\SystemResources\Windows-x86-64\SpecialSimplifiers\Gamma.mx" And indeed... there is no such file...

Comment: It it beginning to sound like your installation of mathematica is corrupt.  I'd suggest you un-install and re-install it.

Comment: I confirm that this bug is no longer present in version 10.0.1

Comment: Can't reproduce on V10.0.1 Mac OS X 10.6. It almost sounds like you've got a virus eating your system files LOL.

Comment: Cannot confirm on Win7 64 and 10.0.1.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the issue cannot be reproduced and may be due to corrupt installation on the OP´s machine.